# Where is the "Custom location" in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

As we know, in xcode 3, there is a "custom location" in project info. Where is it in Xcode 4? I found many "Path" can be set in xcode4's Build Settings, such as "Intermediate Build Files Paths", "Build Product Path", etc. Which one should be set or should all of them be set?
Thanks!

Comment: http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=20275

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting is not necessary to set in xcode 4 as it sets the location automatically.

From [this forum thread](http://forums.omnigroup.com/showthread.php?t=20275):

> You no longer need to do this in Xcode 4; it automatically segregates
>   build products from each workspace in
>   ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData. Instead, you need to make a
>   workspace with the appropriate projects as members (along with your
>   other app/framework targets).
>
> If you look at one of the iOS sample apps, you should be
>   able to just open it and build (since those already have project
>   references for the frameworks and Xcode 4 follows the sample).

---

Check out this doc for specific project/workspace build settings:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html

Comment: I know what you mean. But my project has several child projects. I will use the ".a" lib after they are build. I need to put them in an "lib" folder.

Comment: You can customize that in the [build settings](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW105) with TARGET_BUILD_DIR and BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR, etc.  check out http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/ipad/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW105 for more info.

Comment: Thanks chown. But actually, my problem is that it cannot break at a breakpoint in a ".a" lib generated in a child project. And I put the .a lib path in "Intermediate Build Files Paths", and the main project can build and link. But it can't break at the bp set in the child project, even I set a bp in main projcet. So I wonder which setting is wrong?

Comment: Hmmm, I'm not sure about that then.  What you could do is put `NSLog(@"Something...");` where you want the breakpoint just to make sure that section of code is executing properly.  Another idea is to set a breakpoint in the main project just before a call to the `.a` lib and then *step* through until you reach the line of code in the child.  But without knowing all of the exact settings and structure of your workspace/project, I wouldn't really know how else to fix this.  Sorry @iphoner, wish I could provide more help :/

Comment: It's ok chown. I'm using the second way you mentioned.